# dropdown in Google forms - not able to select the value programatically

Tags: javascript, google-forms

For dropdown in google forms, they don't use select control and it is just a combination of div and classes and even the selection option is based on classes. I can't find a way to programmatically select an option as far as I have seen (I tried few things including the click() event but didn’t work).

Any ideas here could be helpful!

Comment: Please, provide a link to the exact JS library you're using and a code block with the content of the dropdown element used in google forms, so that also who is not familiar with this library can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does Settings > Advanced > Restore settings to their original defaults help?